# File should not be create if No file is return by the server [Wget Command ]

Tags: wget

im executing a  wget command which sends a file to my server and server returns me a file. But the problem is that sometimes the server is OFFLINE then a empty file is created on my side

the command im executing is -

```
 wget --timeout=10 -t 1 --post-file=file_Path/file_Name.extension server_Address --output-document=file_Path/file_Name.extension
```

i want that is sever is down no file should be created at my side

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the file afterwards with appending `|| rm -f file_Path/file_Name.extension`. This should delete the file if wget end with a status code different from 0.

```
wget --timeout=10 -t 1 --post-file=file_Path/file_Name.extension server_Address --output-document=file_Path/file_Name.extension || rm -f file_Path/file_Name.extension
```

Comment: If that is the file wget is creating, then yes.

Comment: Are u sure this command will not remove my file if it is not empty. I mean if server send some data in file

Comment: You are right. I was not aware of this condition. So you want to query the url and only if this works, you want to overwrite the file. Otherwise you want to keep the old version. With this, my answer is not correct.

Comment: file is successfully deleting if it was empty. But I cant Up my server Now. So i cant test

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the old file until the server is available you have to perform an intermediate step:

```
wget --spider -S server_address && wget --timeout=10 -t 1 --post-file=file_Path/file_Name.extension server_Address --output-document=file_Path/file_Name.extension
```